# Program / Script / Method to rename EAC-ripped album of MP3s using Masks

Tags: software-rec, mp3, batch-rename, mask, exact-audio-copy

tl;dr: skip to last paragraph

---

I’ve recently changed the filename format that I use in *Exact Audio Copy* when ripping CDs. I have changed it so that for various-artist CDs, the track number then CD title come first.

This is fine for any new CDs that I rip, but ones that I have already ripped still use the old naming scheme. Obviously, re-ripping them would be much more work than simply renaming them.

The problem is that in addition to just renaming the files, the folder that they are in and the playlist (and preferably also the log) need to be changed as well, so renaming manually, while possible, is also quite a bit of work.

There’s plenty of MP3 renaming utilities, but I have not seen any that specifically make changes to folders, playlists, and logs as well.

Does anyone know of an easy way to do simple renaming of files, folders, and playlists using masks? (Actually, since the tags don’t need to be updated, I don’t technically need an *MP3 renamer*, just a file renamer that can also—automatically—rename the folder and update the filenames inside a text file.)

For example, the files, folder, and entries in the playlist (and log) would need to be changed as follows:

```
old filename/foldername mask and corresponding file/folder-names:
    "Various (%C-%Y)\%A [%T] %N (%C)"

    C:\Various (Foobar OST-2011)\Bob Bobson [Rap Song] 01 (Foobar OST).mp3


new filename/foldername mask and corresponding file/folder-names:
    "Various (%C - %Y)\%N (%D) %A [%T]"

    C:\Various (Foobar OST - 2011)\01 (Foobar OST) Bob Bobson [Rap Song].mp3
```

---

To be clear, the program needs to be able to take a filename/foldername (FNFN) mask corresponding to the existing FNFNs, and rearrange the FNFNs to match new FNFN masks, then update those FNFNs inside some text-files.

(Yes, I know this is the stuff of Perl and regex, but don’t know of any Windows tools that can easily do this task.)

Comment: Perl and regex work on Windows too :p

Comment: @briankb, yes, but if I have to spend time manually writing a script to get it done, then I may as well just do the renaming manually. I’m looking for a ready-made method.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part you can use [Mp3tag](http://mp3tag.de/en/). Its Convert > Filename - Filename feature is exactly what are you looking for. (you can also specify directories with a backslash both in old and new masks, but Mp3tag will not rename them but rather "create new directories below the current working directory")

As for updating the names in the text files...

As long as those files have some regular structure and contain all the same data as MP3s tags you could use Mp3tag again. File > Export allows writing a sophisticated template to render the information into.

Probably not for EAC logs though.

You could also try to utilize a Preview feature of the "Filename - Filename" action. It will create a text file with the "old file name -> new file name" mappings. Then you could probably use it with some batch text replacement program to fix the playlists and logs.

Comment: Thanks for the instructions; I’ve got MP3Tag, but I haven’t been able to do what I need with the bit of testing I had previously done. I’ll take a look at it again with your suggestion.